# Steering not affected by gravity?

Tags: game-engine, physics, logic-bricks

An AI I've created uses steering, is dynamic, but doesn't get affected by gravity. What would be a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the actuator, if you uncheck lock Z velocity it works for me.
Are you sure you have in unchecked? Can you share file?